# Cross-Compile Node Modules for MIPS Architecture

Tags: mips, cross-compiling

I have an onion 2+ (mips/mipsel architecture) and I'm looking to run the node module homebridge. One of it's dependencies is hap-nodejs which needs to be cross-compiled for the onion (along with it's dependencies curve25519, ed25519, and mdns). I've been trying to follow tutorials on how to setup the cross compile environment but I keep getting to a point where I don't understand the error code and googling doesn't help.

How would I go about setting up an environment for and cross compiling node modules for the onion (or mipsel processor)? I'm using a Mac on 10.13 High Sierra.

Comment: A very interesting question. Here's one document about it that I found: https://github.com/netbeast/docs/wiki/Cross-Compile-NPM-modules